# Bootstrap buttons no longer have margins

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It seems that all of the buttons in my Bootstrap application have lost their margins. From what I understand, they get space around them from `display: inline-block`, but that's no longer the case after I updated to the latest version of Bootstrap (3.3.7), jQuery (3.1.1), and jQuery UI (1.12.1). They now appear 0px from each other. Although I can't reproduce the issue in Bootply, inspecting both seems to indicate that they aren't getting any styles from anything I've done.

Here is an example of the markup that is having a problem:

```
<h2 id="header">Personnel</h2>
<div class="pull-right">
  <button if.bind="!isEditing" class="btn btn-primary" click.delegate="setEdit()"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Edit</button>
  <button if.bind="isEditing" class="btn btn-success" click.delegate="saveEdit()"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
  <button if.bind="isEditing" class="btn btn-danger" click.delegate="cancelEdit()"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I've tried completely deleting all of my custom CSS, but that doesn't have any affect on the buttons.

Comment: seems fine to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxNWrj

Comment: Updating a big library like Bootstrap mid-build can be pretty dangerous and have unwanted effects like the one you're experiencing. Can you just add some custom CSS back in to fix it?

Comment: @Coleman Indeed. It's a combination of requirements, specific bugs, and a dash of "it should be ok". I'll probably just add a margin to the buttons in question.